# Why doesn't the removal of "int" keyword in generate any error in following code

Tags: c

Sample program 1. Note `int` in `typedef` in the first line:

```
typedef int (*p)(); //Statement 1
int foo()
{
 return 0;
}
int main()
{    int c;
    p q=foo;
    c=(*q)();
    printf("%d",c);
    return 0;
}
Output:0
```

Sample program 2. All the same, but without `int` in the first line:

```
typedef (*p)(); //Statement 1
int foo()
{
 return 0;
}
int main()
{    int c;
    p q=foo;
    c=(*q)();
    printf("%d",c);
    return 0;
}
Output:0
```

The output is same in both cases. It doesn't generate any errors. Why?

Comment: C89? Implicit `int`? Anything?

Comment: iirc, "int" is an assumed return type if none is specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always post the compiler (and version) that you are using in questions such as this.

My guess is that you are using a C89 compiler which allows implicit int.

Comment: @ouah I compiled with gcc, `-std=c99 -pedantic`, so I assumed the standard allows it. Is gcc too lenient ?

Comment: @cnicutar: C99 removed implicit int.  It is now a constraint violation, which requires the compiler emit a diagnostic message.  That doesn't mean it must fail to compile the code.  Both warnings and errors are considered diagnostic messages.

Comment: @cnicutar It is. `clang -Wall` tells me `quirk.c:4:11: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]`.

Comment: @cnicutar: which future standards?  C99 requires a diagnostic.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Ed S. You're right, I stand corrected. Should have though before I commented :-)

Comment: @cnicutar Use `-pedantic-errors` to get conformance (or a close approximation). gcc is _very_ permissive.

Comment: @DanielFischer Cool, thanks a lot! Didn't know about `-pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 2):

If you compiled in C99 mode, you'd get a diagnostic, but in C89 and pre-standard C, the keyword `int` was optional.

Thus:

```
extern a;

main(argc, argv)
char **argv;
{
    auto i;
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

and other coding styles that are an abomination by modern standards were allowed.  (The variable `a` is an `int`; the argument `argc` is an `int`; the variable `i` is an `int`; the return type of `main()` is an `int`.)  Note that until C99, you weren't supposed to leave off the `return 0;` from `main()`; if you did, the value returned to the calling environment was undefined.