# Why does the following C program compile without error?

Tags: c

My program is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getTriangle(num) {
    if (num == 1) {
        return num;
    } else {
        return num + getTriangle(num - 1);
    }

}

int main() 
{
    int tri = getTriangle(7);
    printf("%i\n", tri);
    return 0;
}
```

I inadvertently made a mistake by not declaring the type of num in my function getTriangle.  In other words the line should read:

```
int getTriangle(int num) {
```

However when I compile

```
make euler012
cc     euler012.c   -o euler012
```

and run

```
./euler012
28
```

Everything appears OK.  Shouldn't this be generating an error or a warning somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C89 and pre-standard C, if you didn't specify a type, `int` was assumed.

See also [Why doesn't the removal of `int` keyword generate any error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980287/why-doesnt-the-removal-of-int-keyword-in-generate-any-error-in-following-code/).

Answer (score 2):

When I compile with warning turned on in `gcc` I see this warning:

```
warning: type of 'num' defaults to 'int' [enabled by default]
   int getTriangle(num) {
```

That flags I am using are `-Wall -W -pedantic`. Having warning turned on by default will save you a lot of problems in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Try with "gcc -std=c99 triangle.c" it will generate an warning.